# linux kernel compilation successful, but no image image generated (nowhere to be found)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to compile linux kernel [5.12.4](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux-5.12.4.tar.xz) which I get from kernel.org and it compiles without any errors but the message you would normally get "image xyz is ready" never appears and no image is found in `./linux-5.12.4/arch/x86/boot`or anywhere else. Here are the commands I am running:

```
cd linux-5.12.4
cp /boot/config-`uname -r` .config
yes '' | make oldconfig
make clean
time make -j`nproc` bzImage
```

Here are the last few lines of the output:

```
  CC      fs/binfmt_elf.o
  CC      fs/compat_binfmt_elf.o
  CC      fs/mbcache.o
  CC      fs/posix_acl.o
  CC      fs/coredump.o
  CC      fs/drop_caches.o
  CC      fs/fhandle.o
  AR      fs/built-in.a

real    0m34.893s
user    14m48.740s
sys 1m36.019s
```

So this is not my first time compiling a kernel but it's been about a year since I did this last time so looks like something has changed and I followed instructions found on various sites and they are showing pretty much the same thing, I don't see what I am missing, I have done this before and it has worked in the past.

I also tried `time make -j32 LOCALVERSION=-custom` but again, no image is generated.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 (AMD Ryzen).

Comment: I wouldn’t expect the build to finish at `fs/built-in.a`. There might be an error further up in the output...

Comment: Ok, I will redirect the output to a file and assess it and will post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem (thanks to Stephen Kitt), indeed, there was an error further up in the output. This is the first time I am seeing an error displayed in such a manner. So I ran this command:

`time make -j32 bzImage > ~/Desktop/log_std.txt 2> ~/Desktop/log_err.txt`

and...

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'debian/canonical-certs.pem', needed by 'certs/x509_certificate_list'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [Makefile:1851: certs] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
arch/x86/hyperv/hv_apic.c: In function ‘hv_send_ipi_mask_allbutself’:
arch/x86/hyperv/hv_apic.c:236:1: warning: the frame size of 1032 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
  236 | }
      | ^
```

Then I found [this](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1081032-start-0.html) post on Gentoo's forums:

```
3193   CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS="n"
You specified that additional keys would be found in file n, but no such file exists. Most likely, you should set this field to be empty, not the string n.
```

When I looked up my `.config` file, indeed, I found this:

`CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS="debian/canonical-certs.pem"`

In my case, I just commented out the line just to see what happens:

`#CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS="debian/canonical-certs.pem"`

then if that didn't work or produced errors, I would have followed the advise given:

```
Most likely, you should set this field to be empty
```

and then

```
`time make -j32 bzImage`

**Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready**  (#2)

real    1m37.761s
user    33m57.677s
sys 4m3.008s
```

Looking at the config (after the compilation), I can now see `CONFIG_SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS=""`

So now it works :)